# T-SQL right outer join doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

I am having trouble with a right join that doesn't seem to be doing what I want.
The query below doesn't bring back all of the records from the grp table.  I'm expecting a few rows matching the 30555 gl record and 30 rows from the grp table with nulls for the gl columns.  Instead I get the expected few rows for the 30555 gl record and only 3 matching grp rows instead of the 30.

```
select gl.Tran_Number, gl.Amount, gl.Cost_Center, ' - ' as blank, grp.*
from GL_DETAIL_MC gl
    right outer join EM_COST_GROUP_LIST_MC grp on grp.Cost_Center_Code = gl.Cost_Center and grp.Company_Code = gl.Company_Code
where
    (gl.Company_Code = 'RCL' or grp.Company_Code = 'RCL')
    and (gl.Tran_Number = '30555     ' or gl.Transaction_ID is null)
```

Not really sure where I've gone wrong here.  Oh and I should mention that I tried creating a similar table structure in a test database and everything works as I expected.  This leads me to thing that there is a database setting that is changing how the query is returning results.

Answer (score 0):

The outer join is fine.  The problem is the `where` clause.

I presume you intend:

```
select gl.Tran_Number, gl.Amount, gl.Cost_Center, ' - ' as blank, grp.*
from EM_COST_GROUP_LIST_MC grp LEFT JOIN
     GL_DETAIL_MC gl
     on grp.Cost_Center_Code = gl.Cost_Center and
        grp.Company_Code = gl.Company_Code and
        gl.Company_Code = 'RCL' and
        gl.Tran_Number = '30555 
where grp.Company_Code = 'RCL' or gl.Company_Code is not null;
```

I much prefer `left join` to `right join`.